# How do I pass the properties from one component to another in React

Tags: reactjs, components, react-props

I am making a pokedex app using pokeapi. I am cannot seem to figure out how I can pass my data from my pokemon list to my single pokemon page.

Basically what I am trying to do is when I click a single pokemon from the list I want it to render the single pokemon data component and transfer the data of the clicked pokemon to that component.

I am using react-router-dom

This is my app.js where I map through all the pokemon stored in the state and return the pokemon list component with the name prop for each item in the state

[image]

Here is my pokemonlist.js

[image]

Here is my single pokemon data component where I want the data from the clicked pokemon to be transferred

[image]

Answer (score 0):

How I would do this :

In your router, you need to have 2 routes (so 2 components) : 1 that display all pokemons and 1 that displays one pokemon,

For the single pokemon route, you can use params of react-router-dom to only display the pokemon which as the id in the URL (you need to use a unique property to each pokemon, for example an id)

It would be something like this :

```
function Router() {
  return (
    <Switch>
      <Route path="/pokemons" exact component={Pokemons} />
      <Route path="/pokemon/:id" exact component={Pokemon} />
    </Switch>
```

All pokemons component
(# example : http://localhost:3000/pokemons (displays all pokemons)

```
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

function Pokemons() {
  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemons();
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {allPokemons.map(pokemon => (
        <Link to={`/pokemon/${pokemon.id}`}>{pokemon.name}</Link>
      ))}
    </>
```

Single pokemon component
(# example : http://localhost:3000/pokemon/150 (displays the pokemon with id 150)

```
import { useParams } from "react-router-dom";

function Pokemon() {
  let { id } = useParams();

  useEffect(() => {
    getPokemon(id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      {pokemon.name}
    </>
```